# Unwanted software installed accidentally

Tags: repository, ubuntu-10.10

On ubuntu 10.10 I accidentally added to repository two programs that had the goal to reproduce a bug.I didn't want to install them, so I kept them in repository and (didn't know how to remove them) when I was upgrading the repository using update manager, I was taking out the mark, so that I was skipping the installation every time.
But yesterday I upgraded the repository using the *upgrade* command from terminal.
So I accidentally (also) installed these two programs.
I tried to use *dpkg* command to try uninstalling them:

```
dpkg -l
dpkg -l | grep "manage the repository"
```

The title of the software I was seeing in update manager was "manage the repository to install software from".
However giving these two commands didn't help me seeing the real name of these two programs.
So I don't know the name of the programs to remove.
I would know if there is a command [b]to see which are the programs I installed in chronological order[/b].Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Update Manager, the *Settings...* button will (after entering your password) take you to a dialogue, which includes an *Other Software* tab, for managing your 3rd party repositories—including PPAs. (There doesn't appear to be a way to resort this; but it's usually not very long.) There you should be able to uncheck the repo that you want to go away. I suspect that this will *not* automatically remove installed software; but i've never tried it.

If what you want is to remove an installed package, then the easiest (providing that you know the exact name of the package) is (at a shell prompt, of course) `apt-get remove <package_name>` or `apt-get purge <package_name>` (the latter being more thorough in that it also removes config files, etc.).